# How to display pygame output on cloud9-vnc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cloud9-ide, vnc

So I'm playing with python3 on Cloud9, got interested in trying pygame and found a recommendation to install cloud9-vnc for a desktop display. Got both of those things to work, but not in tandem. I'm a rather newbish with Linux and VNC, so I'm stuck at the moment. Any chance I can get pygame output on a VNC desktop?

What I have so far is that I've installed pygame using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401342/how-to-download-pygame-in-python3-3) and cloud9-vnc using [this](https://github.com/noobkilervip/cloud9-vnc). Pygame import and commands run smoothly (both in terminal and script) and when I run the script with c9vnc I get the link to a VNC desktop. However, the desktop is clear, apart from Ubuntu logo.

The program doesn't actually seems to be running, considering that it doesn't display the text to be printed

[image]

In fact, it seems that it's not even started to run.

However, inside the VNC desktop I have the access to complete cloud9 workspace, including installed pygame, which does work, albeit a bit more clunky, compared to cloud9's interface.

So what I want to ask is is there a way for me to write and run a code on cloud9's default interface that would directly display the output in VNC's desktop, with little to no additional interaction?

Comment: See [How to run pygame window on vnc remote desktop?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/how-to-run-pygame-window-on-vnc-remote-desktop) and [Access the default running X desktop session over VNC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/access-the-default-running-x-desktop-session-over-vnc).

Comment: Your program doesn't "run", because it has no application (respectively game) loop.